# Updated app will remove existent files

Tags: ios

Help please, I'm new to iOS Development. I have an iOS App which downloads some images from a web server. When I try to re-download those files, my code will check if was downloaded already or not..

Now, my question is:

If I downloaded all necessary files to the Documents directory of my app, what's going to happen if I create a new version/update of this App? I mean, if my customers who have already installed v1.0 and downloaded all necessary files and then update the app from appstore, will all downloaded files be erased?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your user's data will not be lost when updating the app if it is stored in the Documents directory.

The only time this data will be lost is if the user deletes the application of if the user resets his/her phone.